# Creating new MSM site keeps timing out

Tags: multi-site-manager

I'm trying to to create a new MSM site from one of the existing sites but i keep getting 500 internal errors.

Looking in the apache error log it says:

> Thu Mar 10 14:25:54 2016] [error] [client ::1] FastCGI: comm with
>   server "/Applications/MAMP/fcgi-bin/php5.4.42.fcgi" aborted: idle
>   timeout (30 sec), referer:
>   http://example.dev/ycmanage/index.php?S=0&D=cp&C=sites&M=add_edit_site

I have increased max_execution_time & max_input_time to 20 minutes and increased the memory allowance to 1024MB.

What more can i do?!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to increase the -idle-timeout value in your vhost .conf file.

Documentation:

http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiExternalServer

If you are not able to configure this you probably need to figure out how to speed up the execution so it can complete in under 30 seconds. My guess is that MySQL is taking a long time to execute...

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345016/mod-fastcgi-idle-timeout-not-work